# The set of Turing machines that recognize $\{00, 01\}$ is undecidable

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

> $L =\big\{\langle T\rangle \mid T\text{ is a Turing machine that recognizes }\{00, 01\}\big\}$. Prove $L$ is undecidable.

I am really having difficulties even understanding the reduction to use here.

I'm not asking for free lunch, just a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That follows from [Rice's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem):

> **Rice's Theorem.**
>
> Let S be a set of languages that is nontrivial, meaning
>
> - there exists a Turing machine that recognizes a language in S
> - there exists a Turing machine that recognizes a language not in S
>
> Then, it is undecidable to determine whether the language decided by an arbitrary Turing machine lies in S.
>
> [Copied from Wikipedia]

The language $\{00,01\}$ is nontrivial, thus $L$ is not decidable.

*Hint:* It is also easy to prove that directly, not using Rice's theorem. Let $M$ be a Turing machine. Consider Turing machine $M'$ defined as

> > **if** $x\in\{00,\,01\}$ then
> >
> > - run $M$ on empty tape
> > - *accept* (if $M$ halts)
> >
> > **otherwise,** *reject*

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be more precise than this. It has to be constructed. We have to reduce some undecidable language to L to prove by contradiction that L is undecidable, which is where I am confused: what undecidable language do I use?

Comment: Rice's theorem is *precise*. The proof is very rigorous. I added a hint how to prove that $L$ is not decidable directly without using Rice's theorem.